# Print Text (Without File) On Linux With LPR

Tags: linux, printing, lpr

I've seen this done and I used to be able to do it.  I had it documented in a file that was clobbered recently in a backup issue.

I have a text string I want to print from bash using lpr.  I know I can print text files easily, but how can I print text that is just in quotation marks or in a string without first saving it as a file, then printing the file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [here-strings](http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/x15683.html) with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

```
lpr <<< "text string"
```

or if your string is contained in a variable

```
lpr <<< "$var"
```

Comment: I think I also remember it being done with an actual option for the lpr command, as opposed to any piping or redirect.

Comment: @Tango, that is interesting. I do not see such an option with `lpr` on my installation however I am no expert on `lpr`

Comment: I remember it took a lot of scrounging to find it, so it's not well documented, but I remember at one point finding something that was easy and surprised me.  Unfortunately, I must be using different terms with Google now than I did then because I am not finding it.